# Separar strings

Tags: c#, string

Sendo uma `string` com o seguinte formato:

```
string valores = "valor1#valor2#valor3";
```

desejo armazenar os valores separados por `#` em um `array`, tendo um resultado assim:

```
teste[0] = valor1;
teste[1] = valor2;
teste[2] = valor3;
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

<sup>Observação: procurei algumas soluções nesse fórum porém não tive sucesso.</sup>

Comment: já usou var `var teste = valores.Split("#")`?

Comment: amigo, se eu passar por essa linha mais de uma vez eu aumento o número de posições do meu array "teste" automaticamente?

Comment: me explique passar mais de uma vez, se você colocar somente essa linha é gerado somente os valores que o `Split` achar, não entendi varias vezes.?

Comment: deu certo aqui amigo, consegui fazer funcionar esse split(). Obrigadão!!